# Gallery thumbnails are not generated

Tags: magento2.3.1, gallery, thumbnail

We need to import a lot of products from different vendors (about 30000 products). For some products the thumbnails are not generated in the front end.

I tried clearing the cache, clearing static content, running deploy, reindexing, reimporting, everything.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Running Magento 2.3.1

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried running `php bin/magento catalog:image:resize` and/or `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an issue with the template. The template creators fixed the problem.